# Error detected during LiveSync when build android app on NativeScript

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I trying to develop my first app using nativescript but I finding that a bit difficult due to some errors I'm getting...

When I tried to run the app in an emulator I get the error `Error detected during LiveSync on emulator`

This error happens as soon as I start working on the app.. But without too much information.. I installed nativescript-localstorage but no more than that

Also as soon as I open the Sidekick app I get the error:

```
[18-11-08 15:15:22.356] {"extensionName":"nativescript-angular-cli","extensionVersion":"0.1.9","error":{"stack":"Error: Unable to load extension nativescript-angular-cli. You will not be able to use the functionality that it adds. Error: Default commands should be required before child commands\n    at ExtensibilityService.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/extensibility-service.js:101:29)\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/extensibility-service.js:10:58)\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)\n    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)\n    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)\n    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3","message":"Unable to load extension nativescript-angular-cli. You will not be able to use the functionality that it adds. Error: Default commands should be required before child commands","extensionName":"nativescript-angular-cli"}}
OUTPUT 1
```

My app.gradle is

```
android {  
  defaultConfig {  
    generatedDensities = []
  }
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
} 

def settingsGradlePath

if(project.hasProperty("appResourcesPath")){
    settingsGradlePath = "$project.appResourcesPath/Android/settings.gradle";
} else {
    settingsGradlePath = "$rootDir/../../app/App_Resources/Android/settings.gradle";
}

def settingsGradleFile = new File(settingsGradlePath);

if(settingsGradleFile.exists())
{
    apply from: settingsGradleFile;
}
```

And this is my package.json

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.mydomain.company",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "5.0.0"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.0.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~6.1.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "~6.2.0",
    "nativescript-localstorage": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "~5.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~5.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "nativescript-dev-sass": "~1.6.0",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~0.17.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~6.1.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~6.2.0"
  },
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

I tried removing and adding the platforms, deleting the node_modules folder and installing again the nativescript without luck..

Adding device Console

```
ActivityManager: Killing 3555:com.google.android.apps.maps/u0a59 (adj 906): empty #17
ActivityManager: Killing 2480:android.process.acore/u0a1 (adj 906): empty #18
ActivityManager: Start proc 5201:com.google.android.apps.wallpaper/u0a73 for broadcast com.google.android.apps.wallpaper/.module.DailyLoggingAlarmReceiver
ActivityManager: Killing 4035:com.google.android.ext.services/u0a12 (adj 906): empty #17
ActivityManager: Start proc 5777:android.process.acore/u0a1 for content provider com.android.providers.contacts/.VoicemailContentProvider
ActivityManager: Killing 3388:com.google.android.gms.ui/u0a13 (adj 906): empty #17
```

Comment: Could you please post the full error log? Between, are you on Windows / Mac?

Comment: That's the full error that sidekick gave me... I added the device console in case it helps

Comment: Did you try running from CLI?